# How to share an app with a dependency from maven local

Tags: android, gradle, maven-publish

I need to share a source code for a project that depends on libraries in maven local. I am the only one maintaining the project so maven local is enough. Now I have to share my source code so the people can just run `gradle buildRelease` and it will go. But how do I share the maven local dependencies?

in the gradle I have

```
...
    implementation("us.my.project:that-project:1.5.0") {
```

that obviously works only on my machine. So I deleted that line and added the .aar manualy

```
...
    implementation files('libs/that-project-1.5.0.aar')
...
```

but now that doesnt add the dependencies contained in `that-project`.

I have a pom.xml but I can't find a way how to import that..?

I can't import `that-project` as a module and somehow package it with it because I would have to do so for another 7 modules across 5 different projects and that's just crazy for a one time export.

So is there any way to include all the dependencies in one zip file?

NOTE: `that-project` has a dependency on `another-project` which also lives on maven local (there is about 5 projects)

Comment: Since you said "include all the dependencies", couldn't you use the `shadow` plugin?  It will include all sub-dependencies in a "fat jar" for your downstream consumers.  https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow

Comment: @User51 Actually, no. It needs to look like when you download a project from git. So I am not really interested in a jar, I just need all the dependencies from maven local in that folder. But .aar is not working since it doesnt include any dependecies or extra gradle file or anything like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is copying the `~/.m2/repositories` folder into your `app/libs` folder. Then in your gradle define the directory as your maven repo.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url uri("${rootProject.projectDir}/app/libs/repository")
    }
}
```

After you defined your repository you can access your artifacts the same way you have been accessing them before:

```
implementation("us.my.project:that-project:1.5.0")
```

This approach makes it easy to zip your folder and send the full source code including your local maven dependencies.